# FME FTP Caller - does not download file

Tags: fme-form, ftp

In FME Workbench 2019 I am trying to use the FTPCaller as below

[image]

It runs but I don't see an update to the file. The first version of this was manually downloaded into the folder as the "Target File" didn't allow just a folder to be used and there had to be a file in place. This should probably be changed to download location and download file name.

The log is below...I have changed some links for security.

```
Feature Caching is ON
The workspace may run slower because features are being recorded on all output ports.
 
    Command-line to run this workspace:
        "C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" "J:\Property Update FME Model\Property_BPoly_Update.fmw"
              --SourceDataset_MAPINFO "J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\Cassowary Coast RC\cassowary_coast_i_bpoly.TAB"
              --SourceDataset_MAPINFO_5 "J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\Property_Template.TAB"
              --SourceDataset_MAPINFO_4 "J:\Property Update FME Model\Input\Cassowary Coast RC\cassowary_coast_i_fpoint.TAB"
              --DCDB_Data "<at>DateTimeFormat<openparen><at>DateTimeNow<openparen><closeparen><comma>%d<solidus>%m<solidus>%Y<closeparen>"
              --DestDataset_MAPINFO "J:\Property Update FME Model\FME_Scratch"
              --DestDataset_MAPINFO_2 "J:\Property Update FME Model\FME_Scratch\SSA"
    
Starting translation...
FME 2019.0.2.0 (20190605 - Build 19260 - WIN64)
FME_HOME is 'C:\Program Files\FME\'
FME Professional Edition 
Permanent License.
Machine host name is: 
START - ProcessID: 18148, peak process memory usage: 32664 kB, current process memory usage: 32524 kB
FME Configuration: Command line arguments are `C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe' `J:/Property Update FME Model\wb-xlate-1597109461276_18352' `LOG_STANDARDOUT' `YES' `LogCountServerName' `{33212ae0-9bd5-4211-abbe-1d87c3276979}'
FME Configuration: Connection Storage: 'C:\Users\George.Corea\AppData\Roaming\Safe Software\FME\'
Shared folders for formats are : C:\Program Files\FME\datasources;C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\Formats
Shared folders for transformers are : C:\Users\George.Corea\AppData\Roaming\Safe Software\FME\Packages\19260-win64\transformers;C:\Program Files\FME\transformers;C:\Users\George.Corea\AppData\Roaming\Safe Software\FME\FME Store\Transformers
Shared folders for coordinate systems are : C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystems
Shared folders for coordinate system exceptions are : C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystemExceptions
Shared folders for coordinate system grid overrides are : C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\CoordinateSystemGridOverrides
Shared folders for CS-MAP transformation exceptions are : C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\CsmapTransformationExceptions
Shared folders for transformer categories are : C:\Users\George.Corea\Documents\FME\TransformerCategories
FME Configuration: Reader Keyword is `MULTI_READER'
FME Configuration: Writer Keyword is `MULTI_WRITER'
FME Configuration: Writer Group Definition Keyword is `MULTI_WRITER_DEF'
FME Configuration: Reader type is `MULTI_READER'
FME Configuration: Writer type is `MULTI_WRITER'
FME Configuration: No destination coordinate system set
FME Configuration: Current working folder is `J:\Property Update FME Model'
FME Configuration: Temporary folder is `C:\Users\GEORGE~1.COR\AppData\Local\Temp', set from environment variable `TEMP'
FME Configuration: FME_HOME is `C:\Program Files\FME\'
FME Configuration: FME_BASE is 'no'
FME Configuration: FME_MF_DIR is 'J:\Property Update FME Model/'
FME Configuration: FME_MF_NAME is 'Property_BPoly_Update.fmw'
FME Configuration: FME_PRODUCT_NAME is 'FME(R) 2019.0.2.0'
System Status: 61.87 GB of disk space available in the FME temporary folder (C:\Users\GEORGE~1.COR\AppData\Local\Temp)
System Status: 128.00 TB of virtual memory available
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 64-bit  (Build 14393)
FME Platform: WIN64
Locale: en_AU
Code Page: 1252  (ANSI - Latin I)
FME Configuration: Process limit is 31.85 GB of physical memory
FME Configuration: Start freeing memory when process usage exceeds 95.54 GB of virtual memory
FME Configuration: Stop freeing memory when process usage is below 71.66 GB of virtual memory
Creating writer for format: 
Creating reader for format: 
MULTI_READER(MULTI_READER): Will fail with first member reader failure
Using Multi Reader with keyword `MULTI_READER' to read multiple datasets
Using MultiWriter with keyword `MULTI_WRITER' to output data (ID_ATTRIBUTE is `multi_writer_id')
Writer output will be ordered by value of multi_writer_id
Loaded module 'LogCount_func' from file 'C:\Program Files\FME\plugins/LogCount_func.dll'
FME API version of module 'LogCount_func' matches current internal version (3.8 20181030)
Emptying factory pipeline
Router and Unexpected Input Remover (RoutingFactory): Tested 0 input feature(s), wrote 0 output feature(s): 0 matched merge filters, 0 were routed to output, 0 could not be routed.
Unexpected Input Remover Nuker (TeeFactory): Cloned 0 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
cassowary_coast_i_fpoint (MAPINFO_3) Splitter (TeeFactory): Cloned 0 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
cassowary_coast_i_bpoly (MAPINFO_1) Splitter (TeeFactory): Cloned 0 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
Property_Template (MAPINFO_2) Splitter (TeeFactory): Cloned 0 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
Destination Feature Type Routing Correlator (RoutingFactory): Tested 0 input feature(s), wrote 0 output feature(s): 0 matched merge filters, 0 were routed to output, 0 could not be routed.
Final Output Nuker (TeeFactory): Cloned 0 input feature(s) into 0 output feature(s)
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
                            Features Read Summary
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
==============================================================================
Total Features Read                                                          0
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
                           Features Written Summary
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
==============================================================================
Total Features Written                                                       0
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-
-~                                                                             ~-
-~    Feature caches have been recorded at every stage of the translation.     ~-
-~                      To inspect the recorded features,                      ~-
-~              click the feature cache icons next to the ports.               ~-
-~                                                                             ~-
-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-
Translation was SUCCESSFUL with 7 warning(s) (0 feature(s) output)
FME Session Duration: 0.3 seconds. (CPU: 0.0s user, 0.2s system)
END - ProcessID: 18148, peak process memory usage: 37036 kB, current process memory usage: 36796 kB
Translation was SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the file does not update is because you have Feature Caching switched on. If you have run the workbench before, the part which hasn't changed and had no changes upstream won't run again. It's results are in the cache.

You can switch off Feature Caching under Run --> Enable Feature Caching.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I've attached the FMW with an opensource link to an FTP download in the following link - does this work for you? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y9Nlo_LvIIW0XyhMx6KweQ8q5atdct0g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It won't run as you uploaded it, because the workflow is missing an initiator. The red colored inputport of the FTPCaller is the indication of this. If you place a Creator before the FTPCaller an connect them the inputport turns grey. A file of 80 MB got downloaded.